# Change user type and delete user

Tags: python, django

I'm currently building a rental system in Python using Django but I have no idea how to change their type(e.g from normal user to Premium User) or delete them **as an admin**

Here's what i've tried so far for changing status/type:

```
def admin_changeuserstat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.COOKIES.get("session_adminId"):
            if User.isNormalUser:
                # Here's what I'm stuck where I wanna change to Premium user
            else:
                #do anything
        else: 
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"error": "please login as admin"}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"error": "require POST"}))
```

Here's what i've tried for deleting user:

```
def admin_userdelete(request,username):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       user = User.objects.get(username=username)
       if request.user == user:
           logout(request)
           user.delete()
           return redirect("/")
       else:
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"error": "Only admin can do so"}))
   else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"error": "require POST"}))
```

Comment: if User.isNormalUser: User.isNormalUser = False User.ispremiumUser = True

Comment: @Boomerang20thCentury ok what about the deleting user function. did i get it right?

Comment: post your logout function. Did the first function work ?